# number theory modular arithmrtic system with primes.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

For how many distinct primes pqr can we have 
$$pq \equiv 1 \bmod r$$
$$pr \equiv 1 \bmod q$$
$$rq \equiv 1 \bmod p$$???

I've never arrived at something like this before ( i got here wile doing an olympiad problem)

Comment: $(p,q,r)=(2,3,5)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given congruences imply
$$
pqr\mid pq+qr+rp-1
$$
This is because $p,q,r$ primes means that it suffices to verify that each of $p,q,$ and $r$ divide $pq+qr+rp-1$, but this is clear.
Now clearly $pq+qr+rp-1>0$, so then we have $pqr\le pq+qr+rp-1$. WLOG assume that $p\ge q\ge r\ge 2$. Then
$$
q(qr-q-r)\le p(qr-q-r)\le qr-1\Rightarrow q^2(r-1)-2qr\le-1
$$
But then
$$
qr(\frac{q}{2}-2)\le\frac{q^2r}{2}-2qr\le q^2(r-1)-2qr<0
$$
So $q\le 3$.

If $q=2$, then $p=2$, so $4r\mid 4r+3$, which is impossible for $r\ge 2$.

If $q=3$ and $p=2$, then $6r\mid 5(r+1)$, so $r\mid 5$ give $r=5$ as the only possibility.

If $q=3$ and $p=3$, then $9r\mid 6r+8$, so $r\mid 2$, a contradiction.

Comment: How did you think of that?

Comment: In general, for these types of olympiad problems a common strategy is to use bounding to limit the number of possible cases, and then do casework to finish.

Comment: yes, what I couldn't think of was using the reflexive property of the equations to add them and get the strong result that pqr devided the sum